# Sum the value of a property from obejcts that are matching in another property, from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, and I'm trying to sum the value of the `amount` property from each object in the array, based on their `address` property

I would like to convert something like this:

```
[
  {
    amount: 10,
    address: a01,
    ...other props...
  },
  {
    amount: 20,
    address: b02,
    ...other props...
  },
  {
    amount: 5,
    address: a01,
    ...other props...
  },
  ...
]
```

to:

```
[
  {
    address: a01,
    totalAmount: 15,
    ...other props...
  },
  {
    address: b02,
    totalAmount: someTotaledAmount,
    ...other props...
  },
  ...
]
```

Should I be using `reduce` to consolidate the objects in the array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the amounts by address. We'd create an object with an entry for each value of address.

We can then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the result as an array.

```js
let input = [ { amount: 10, address: 'a01', otherValue: 'x' }, { amount: 20, address: 'b02', otherValue: 'y' }, { amount: 5, address: 'a01', otherValue: 'z' } ]

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, { amount, address, ...rest }) => { 
    acc[address] = acc[address] || { address, ...rest, totalAmount: 0 };
    acc[address].totalAmount += amount;
    return acc;
} , {}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could also use a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to do the same thing:

```js
let input = [ { amount: 10, address: 'a01', otherValue: 'x' }, { amount: 20, address: 'b02', otherValue: 'y' }, { amount: 5, address: 'a01', otherValue: 'z' } ]

let result = {};
for(let { amount, address, ...rest} of input) {
    if (!result[address]) {
       result[address] = { address, ...rest, totalAmount: 0 };
    }
    result[address].totalAmount += amount;
}
result = Object.values(result);
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to include other properties from the objects in the original array into the final result?

Comment: You could update the logic to do this, depending on how you wish to include the additional properties into the final result. I'll update the answer to give an idea of how this might work. One can't keep each value, since the output array length is lower than the input.